# Is there any way by which I can name the attached pdf file in flask mail?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ubuntu-14.04, flask-mail

I am using flask-mail to send a mail that would include a pdf document as an attachment, 
The problem is when I receive it in my email the document's name turns out to be "noname" (without any extension), Even though this document is downloadable and readable there are some exceptional cases (probably 1 out of 10) where the document cannot be opened(probably because the extension is not set).

```
def send_mail_flask_to_user(self, doc_name, document_id, email,approve):
    app.config.update(self.mail_settings)
    mail = Mail(app)
    with app.app_context():
        msg = Message(sender=app.config.get(
            "MAIL_USERNAME"), recipients=[email])
        msg.subject = '{} Coriolis Tech'.format(doc_name)
        msg.body=""" Dear {},
                     your request for {} has be approved and generated,please find the attachment for the same""".format(email.split('.')[0],doc_name)
        working_dir=os.getcwd()
        link = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/{}/".format(document_id)
        if (approve==True):
            with open(working_dir+"/generated_docs/"+document_id+".pdf",'rb') as fh:
                msg.attach(working_dir+"/"+document_id+".pdf","application/pdf",fh.read())
        elif(approve==False):
            msg.body=""" Your {} is rejected ,contact Division of Human Resource Coriolis Technologies to know more""".format(doc_name)
        mail.send(msg)
```

This problem only persists on Ubuntu 14.04 ,where as it works fine on a Windows machine[image: Screenshot of received email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename parameter has to be a string.extension(eg: "something.pdf") to name the attachment that would be received
eg: your 'abcdcdhhcbdhbcvh.pdf' file that you want to attach would be named as "something.pdf" in the attachment
Hence replace the `msg.attach(working_dir+"/"+document_id+".pdf","application/pdf",fh.read())` line with `msg.attach(filename="something.pdf",disposition="attachment",content_type="application/pdf",data=fh.read())`